# Iterate over pairs of chunks without creating a temporary vector

Tags: iterator, rust

I'm trying to iterate a vector as pairs of chunks (in my case it's an image represented as a contiguous bitmap and I'd like to have access to pixels from two rows at once).

The problem is that I can't do `.chunks(w).chunks(2)`, but have to create a temporary vector in between.

Is there a way to do it purely with iterators? (I'm OK if the result is an iterator itself)

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=018f53ec5081bc11893b63b212418394&version=nightly)

```
let input: Vec<_> = (0..12).collect();

let tmp: Vec<_> = input.chunks(3).collect();
let result: Vec<_> = tmp.chunks(2).collect();

println!("{:?}", result);
```

> [[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], [[6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, I've got it! I can split larger chunks:

```
input
   .chunks(2 * 100)
   .map(|pair| pair.split_at(100))
```

Answer (score 6):

> Oh, I've got it! I can split larger chunks:
>
> `input.chunks(2*3).map(|dbl| dbl.split_at(3)).collect();`

Yes, or you could do this:

```
let tmp: Vec<_> = input
    .chunks(2 * 3)
    .map(|x| x.chunks(3).collect::<Vec<_>>())
    .collect();
```

This outputs exactly the same thing as your example, without the mix of tuples and arrays from your solution:

```
[[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], [[6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]]
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a solution that creates two iterators, one for odd lines and one for even lines. Then combine the two using `.zip()`, which gives an iterator filled with pairs:

```
fn main() {
    let input: Vec<_> = (0..12).collect();

    let it1 = input
        .chunks(3)
        .enumerate()
        .filter_map(|x| if x.0 % 2 == 0 { Some(x.1) } else { None });
    let it2 = input
        .chunks(3)
        .enumerate()
        .filter_map(|x| if x.0 % 2 != 0 { Some(x.1) } else { None });

    let r: Vec<_> = it1.zip(it2).collect();

    println!("{:?}", r);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Indeed `chunk(a).chunk(b)` is not possible because `chunk()` is only available on a slice, whereas the result of `chunk()` (a `Chunk`) is not a slice. That's too bad, I don't know what prevents chunk to be implemented on a regular `Iterator`. (Maybe a lifetime issue?)

A more verbose solution, but still iterator-oriented (i.e., not falling back to an ugly C++-like collecting loop) would be to use the [itertools](https://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/) crate, more specifically the method [batching()](https://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.batching). This is the example from the docs, it does almost the same thing as your `chunk(2)` except it returns a tuple instead of a slice:

```
extern crate itertools;

use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    // An adaptor that gathers elements up in pairs
    let pit = (0..4).batching(|it| match it.next() {
        None => None,
        Some(x) => match it.next() {
            None => None,
            Some(y) => Some((x, y)),
        },
    });

    itertools::assert_equal(pit, vec![(0, 1), (2, 3)]);
}
```

Comment: I think using `Some(x) => (x, it.next().unwrap_or(&[]))` should work fine -- it handles the uneven case (if applicable) by filling in an empty slice.